# Looking for alternatives to QuickBooks online

Tags: webapp-rec

Looking to keep books for a non-profit organization via an online accounting system.  It should have basic accounting functions including the ability to add and track vendors and donors (customers?).

I prefer a secure online solution versus client only software to facilitate access to multiple people.

Comment: What's wrong with Quickbooks Online? Is there something specific you're looking for that they don't offer?

Comment: Personally I think Quickbooks overcharges for a lot of their products. I use their POS (which cost nearly $2,000) and can't add extra users without buying the latest version for the current station and their "upgrade" pricing is not discounted much.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple:

- [www.clarityaccounting.com](http://www.clarityaccounting.com)
- http://www.xero.com

I had come across a really good one in the [Joel On Software Business of Software Forums](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/?biz), but I am having trouble finding it again.

Comment: I have a Xero personal account, which seems quite nice. The company-level features look pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

[inDinero](https://indinero.com/) recently launched in the US. See [this Techcrunch post](http://techcrunch.com/2010/07/02/indinero-launches-as-the-mint-com-for-small-businesses/) for more info.

While it looks interesting, I don't think its a full accounting package and probably can't replace Quickbooks online.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Wave Accounting](http://waveapps.com). It's simple, easy to use and free for life online accounting.

Disclaimer: I work for Wave

Comment: What's your affiliation with them?

Comment: @dnbrv good point, I should have mentioned that I work for Wave (added a disclaimer)